# Is it possible to have multiple src folders in the same folder in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, compilation, directory, src

[The contents of the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHE81.jpg)

I am currently writing programs in the blue src folder here. However, I also moved in other projects into the same folder. Is there some way that will allow me to compile both the programs I have in the src folder and also the programs in  the other src folders in the other projects (ex. the src folder in Chapter 2 or Chapter 4)?

Answer (score 2):

As far as folders go, you can have as many source folders as you want. Just go to Project Structure -> Modules -> Your Module, click on the Sources Tab, select the folder you want to be Source and click the "Mark as: Sources" button. 
The problem you're facing I'm guessing that's you have the same classes from two different versions of the same module. Basically you have class "a.b.Class1" from chapter 1 and "a.b.Class1" from chapter 2. In this case you are gonna have problems because two classes can't have the same package and name. To solve this issue you could just refactor each folder moving all the classes inside to a distinctive package for that source folder. for instance, in the example where you have class "a.b.Class1" in src1 and src2, you can move all classes in src1 to a package that starts with chapter1 for instance, and you'll get "chapter1.a.b.Class1". Respectively, for src2, you can move all classes to a package that starts with chapter2, and you'll get "chapter2.a.b.Class1". This way you won't have any conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

The source directory represents a single module, if you want multiple modules in a single project, each one has its own src directory.